# How do I group and order with sql at the same time?

Tags: sql, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

I have got the following sqlite3 table:

```
Name | LastUpdated | Status
============================
Adam | 2011-05-28  | 1
Bob  | 2011-05-05  | 6
Adam | 2011-05-27  | 2
Adam | 2011-05-16  | 1
Adam | 2011-05-26  | 3
Bob  | 2011-05-18  | 1
Adam | 2011-05-29  | 6
```

and I want to select the a row per Name ordered by the LastUpdated column. So I want to get this data:

```
Adam | 2011-05-29  | 6
Bob  | 2011-05-18  | 1
```

I think I have to do a subquery, but I can't figure out how to go about it.

Comment: Doesn't makes sense - the bob record you want has the earliest date; Adam's is the latest...

Comment: I just figured it out. SELECT Name, MAX(LastUpdated), Status FROM [table] GROUP BY Name

Comment: doing it that way, you will get an arbitrary status field, not the one that corresponds to the MAX(LastUpdated) column - if that is what you wanted. In your examples, you showed the 'status' field with 'Bob' as '1', which is the status field for the latest updated date...

Answer (score 3):

SQLite (and MySQL) support:

```
  SELECT t.name, 
         MAX(t.lastupdated), 
         t.status 
    FROM [table] t 
GROUP BY t.name
```

But most other databases would require you to use:

```
SELECT a.name, a.lastupdate, a.status
  FROM YOUR_TABLE a
  JOIN (SELECT t.name, MAX(t.lastupdated) AS max_lastupdated
          FROM YOUR_TABLE t
      GROUP BY t.name) b ON b.name = a.name
                        AND b.max_lastupdated = a.lastupdated
```

...though this will return duplicates if a name has more than one record with the same highest date value.

Comment: What if they have different status, but same date? Also, you're not aggregating on status - wouldn't that throw an error? I think the requirement was to only group on the name, and select latest of everything else based on the date (or as I understood it)..

Comment: @M.R.: SQLite (and MySQL) pick an arbitrary row - http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset - for columns that are not withing aggregate functions or the group by.  It's actually part of the ANSI standard.

Comment: But you don't want that, right? Wasn't the requirement to pick the latest 'status' as well, per the lastUpdatedDate field? Because for the row that has 'Bob', he has shown the status field that has the latest date...

Comment: @M.R.: It's up to the OP, not me to determine what is right.  It's the OP's comment to the question saying it solved their issue.

Comment: OK - but I would never leave that to be arbitrary... not sure what purpose it serves based on the group by...

Answer (score 1):

You could do it as a self-join.  In this case, I've called the table "table," substitute your own table name in:

```
SELECT
  test.Name,
  test.LastUpdated,
  test.Status
FROM
  test INNER JOIN 
    ( SELECT
        Name,
        MAX(LastUpdated) AS LatestUpdated
      FROM
        test
      GROUP BY
        Name ) AS latest
    ON test.Name = latest.name AND test.LastUpdated = latest.LatestUpdated;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
       t.Name, 
       (Select LastUpdated from [table] t1 where t.name = t1.name order by lastUpdated desc LIMIT 1) as LastUpdated, 
       (Select Status from [table] where t1.name = t.name order by lastUpdated desc LIMIT 1) as Status
FROM [table] t
GROUP by Name
```

Comment: There's no correlation, so that will return the most recent status & lastupdated of all the records.  Why you'd use a subselect instead of MAX, I don't know...

Comment: duh... edited it. I could have used MAX as well ... first instinct just appeared to be subselect :/